# What changes with difficulty?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

So far I've just been playing through on normal, but it has me wondering what exactly is different if I play on Hard or the last one (Lunatic?).

Do the enemies get stronger? Is the math for combat changed somehow? Are my units weaker? Are there more enemy units?

What exactly changes with each step up in difficulty?

Answer (score 3):

I found a post [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643003-fire-emblem-awakening/66856658):

> Enemies have higher stats
>   Enemies have more skills
>   There are more enemies
>   Reeking Boxes cost 4800 G as opposed to 500 G on Normal
>   Reinforcements attack on the turn they spawn (always with warning they're coming)
>   Enemies are aggro'd more easily (i.e. enemies attack in larger groups)
>   Enemies have stronger weapons from earlier in the game and cap out at stronger weapons (typically +4mt +10 hit forges of the strongest basic weapons, as opposed to having just the strongest basic weapons)
>   The cumulative level cap is higher
>   Staff users (and dancers?) gain less EXP

- I can confirm that Reeking Boxes are extremely expensive, and usually not worth the cost of purchase.
- Reinforcements also do attack on the turn they appear, which has been a major cause of restarts for me.  I'm not sure what is meant by warning, as I rarely get any.  I don't know if that's a thing in Normal, though.
- They do use blue (customized) weapons, but I don't know how that compares to Normal.
- I would not be surprised to have reduced XP for support characters.  First thing I did was turn Olivia into a Myrmidon, and that solved her leveling issues.